# MAMP Start Page redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, mamp, redirect-loop

I've been developing PHP sites for a while now using MAMP on my mac with no problems. This morning, I noticed the MAMP start page, from which you can access phpmyadmin (amongst other things), no longer loads in Firefox or Safari giving the warning message (Too Many Redirects occurred).

Bizzarely, the start page works fine in Chrome, and I can get to phpmyadmin fine. Also, all of my PHP sites still work fine, regardless of browser.

The apache error log gives me this message:
    [Mon Jan 07 13:25:37 2013] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store

I tried deleting the .ds_store file, but it had no effect. Can anybody suggest what may be causing the issue here, and how may I go about fixing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

It was caused by a conflicting cookie that had been set by a CMS I was using for another site, on localhost.

Comment: I am not using any CMS, using `ngork` but getting same issue?

Answer (score 5):

I came here after a new [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) installation caused my MAMP server to throw a "too many redirects" error. I installed Jupyter by way of [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-navigator), and apparently they both run on the same set of ports - 8888 and 8889 were both captured by Jupyter, supposedly causing the error (note that MAMP uses 8888 for Apache and 8889 for MySQL by default).

I went to MAMP -> Preferences -> ports and then changed the ports Apache & MySQL ports to random numbers. Anything over 10000 should probably be safe, but I went for the high 20000's just in case.

Comment: This was my case. Thank you.

Comment: this is exactly my case (i think). So I tried what you said, and now my MAMP page loads, but not my wordpress webpage